# How to dynamically access column properties in a With Range statement for conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a script to take an easy look into my data. The data is structured as follows:

- Row 1: Parameter Name
- Row 2: Lower Limit
- Row 3: Upper Limit
- Row 4: Unit
- Row 5 and below: data (can go up to a couple thousands lines and couple hundred columns).

The thing I want to achieve is a script which formats each cell from row 5 down, to color green if it is in between the limits, and to color red if it is not. Each cell should look to it's own column row 2 and 3 for the limits.

I have tried going cell per cell, or column by column. Both worked fine on smaller datasets, but showed problems (excel freezing and eventually closing) on bigger datasets.

I am now trying to format a complete range (because excel has no problems when I do a big range in one piece by hand whatsoever) at once, but I can't access the individual column properties.

The code I am using:

```
With formatRange
    .FormatConditions.Delete

    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & Cells(2, formatRange.Column).Address, Formula2:="=" & Cells(3, formatRange.Column).Address
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 249, 49)
End With
```

Now say my range is from A5:B10.
`formatRange` will be A5:B10.

I would expect every cell from A5:A10 to compare their values against A2 and A3. This is indeed the case

But the cells of B5:B10 also compare their values against A2 and A3.

So my question is, is there a scalable way I can make range B5:B10 look at B2 and B3 instead?

**Edit**

The answer of @Ryan B. is an easy and correct way of doing it by hand.
The problem in vba turned out to be the following:

`Formula1:="=" & Cells(2, formatRange.Column).Address` would ultimately result in `Formula1:="=$A$2"`

As suggested by the accepted answer, this needed to change to `Formula1:="=A$2"` to work.

The solution I found was to create a function which cut of the first character, and create the correct formula this way.

Comment: What is `formatRange`? `A5:A10`? `A5:B10`?  - `formatRange.Column` will return the first column in a multi-column range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by tricking Excel's absolute and relative referencing within conditional formulas.  No VBA is going to be required.  Here is a quick mock of how I understand your data:

[image]

Select the first cell of your 'Row 5' range -- where you're going to apply the conditional formulas.

1. Open the conditional formatting dialog from the Styles button group in the Home Ribbon (this is B5 in my mock-up),
2. Create a 'New Rule'
3. Choose 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format' rule type
4. Begin typing the following rule.  You will have to be quite careful and avoid all use of the arrow keys.  If you need to get to a different point in the formula, use your mouse to move the insertion point.  Make the proper adjustment in your formula if that initial column isn't column 'B' in your worksheet

   =AND( B5 >= B$2, B5 < B$3)

   Pay special notice to the Dollar Signs.  There are NO absolute references used for the target cell, B5.  There are absolute references (that's the dollar sign) in front of the row numbers for Lower and Upper, but not on the columns.
5. Set you're desired look for the "in-bounds" formatting and select OK.
6. Repeat the steps for your "out-of-bounds" formatting.  Use the formula

   =OR( B5 < B$2, B5 >= B$3)

Finally, to apply the formulas to your entire range:

1. Select the cell with the prepared formulas (B5 in this example) and hit [ctrl] + [c] to put excel into cut/copy mode
2. Select the entire target range
3. Right click and take 'Paste Special' from the context menu
4. Paste as formats

And your formatting should propagate through the worksheet.

[image]

Hope it helps.  Always experiment on a copy of your workbook :)

Comment: This is indeed the way to do it by hand, works like a charm! Not only that, but reading through this also brought me to the solution to the problem in vba, so I will accept this as an answer and add the vba way into my question above. Thank you :)